# NSString stringWithFormat: with random number of replacements

Tags: cocoa, nsstring

I am reading in a list of strings, each of which can contain a number of placeholders (%@). I would like to use stringWithFormat: to insert the appropriate value but this works for only one substitution. What can I use to substitute all the values? Is there some sort of string substitution function?

This is an example of what I am trying to do (a little bit of pseudo code):

```
NSString[] patterns = { "my name is %@ every day", "my name is %@ and it will remain %@" };
foreach (NSString s in patterns )
{
    // sometimes the string has one substitution, and sometimes
    // more. The project where I am doing this throws a BAD_ACCESS
    // error if more than one substitution is required so need
    // to take a different approach?
    print [NSString stringWithFormat:s, "Jack"];
}
```

Comment: Please post the code of what you current have. From there people can make suggestion.

Comment: +1 to Black Frog. Do you have the values in an array or a dictionary or what?

Comment: I added an example to illustrate what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell `stringWithFormat:` to use the same argument repeatedly by specifying the position. See [String Format Specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265). Example:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1$@ is the first argument, and so is %1$@",@"this"];
// creates "this is the first argument, and so is this"
```

You could also use [stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString%3awithString%3a) to replace all instances of "%@", but this requires that you do each argument separately and they must be strings:

```
[@"%@ is the first argument, and so is %@" stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%@" withString:@"this"];
```

Comment: This will probably do the trick ... will check it out when I get home :-) Thank you.